# Why does CentOS notifies me "Login with home=/" althought home directory is created already?

Tags: centos

Let me clarify my question.

I have a CentOS 6 virtual machine, with `/home` directory mounted on a logical volume (formed by 2 virtual HDDs). I used this command to create a new user named **user03**

> useradd user03 -c "User 03"

and give him a password:

> passwd user03

Everything happened normally. But when I log in with user03, CentOS give me this notification:

> No directory /home/user03!
>
> Logging in with home = "/"

The weird thing is: /home/user03/ does exists and associated with user03 and user03 has full access. When I do this

> [user03@vm0 /]$ cd
>
> [user03@vm0 ~]$ pwd
>
> /home/user03

working directory changes back to /home/user03/ as it's supposed to do.

So is there anything wrong with my system? Why does it tell me that "No directory /home/..." while that directory does exists?

Comment: What is output of `ls -ld /home`?

Comment: @cuonglm 
It said:
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 4096 Jan 15 14:05 /home

Comment: How about `ls -ld /home/user03`?

Comment: For that, it said:  
> drwx------. 2 user03 user03 4096 Jan 15 14:51 /home/user03

Comment: The permission seems to be fine. Maybe it's selinux issue. Try `restorecon -r /home` then try login again.

Comment: @cuonglm: Thanks alot! That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[This comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179211/why-does-centos-notifies-me-login-with-home-althought-home-directory-is-crea#comment298002_179211) was right, it's an SELinux problem. Running this command and then logging in again fixes the problem:

```
restorecon -r /home
```

Answer (score 0):

The `useradd` command will create home directory if `CREATE_HOME   yes` was set in `/etc/login.defs` file.

From `useradd` manual:

> ```
>        Create the user's home directory if it does not exist. The files and directories contained in the skeleton directory (which can be defined
>        with the -k option) will be copied to the home directory.
>        useradd will create the home directory unless CREATE_HOME in /etc/login.defs is set to no.
> ```

But since you said `/home/user03` exists and belongs to `user03` and proper permissions are set to it, The problem may cause from your `/etc/passwd` file Otherwise do the following:

```
mkdir /home/user03
chown user03:user03 /home/user03
cp /etc/skel/* /home/user03
chmod 700 /home/user03
```

The 6th field is the user home address, maybe your `/etc/passwd` file is disturbed or `useradd` didn't add this field to this file (I don't know what happened!). However you can edit this file and add the user home address to it.

My userid in `/etc/passwd` file is this:

```
Sepahrad:x:500:500:Sepahrad:/home/Sepahrad:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks @sepahrad-salour ! I checked the /etc/passwd and here's the result:  
`user03:x:502:502:Utilisateur 03:/home/user03:/bin/bash`  
  
So that means passwd does add this field, right?

Comment: x in 2th filed means your password is hashed and stored in `/etc/shadow/` file, Please read my post again.

Comment: Cool, your `useradd` command translated the comment field for you :-) Are the home directories mounted via `autofs` perhaps?

Comment: @SepahradSalour: thanks. I did as what you posted but it's the same. It seems there's nothing wrong with `/etc/passwd` or permissions of `/home/user03/`. `CREATE_HOME yes` is in `/etc/login.defs` so that why `/home/user03/` is created. I'm really confused where this error comes from.

Comment: @wurtel: oh it's not smart like that :D, it's because I modified the comment field with `usermod`. `/home/` is manually mounted via `fstab` file.

Comment: @Tuan LE, I'm really confused too! Try to disable selinux via root with `setenforce 0` any logging again!

Comment: @Tuan LE, Please bring us the output of `cat /etc/mtab` file too.

Answer (score -1):

My solution has been to change the permission of home directory.

```
chmod 777 /home
```

I know, give all permissions for all users is not the best solution but at the moment it works fine.

Comment: this is very bad idea

Comment: `755` would be better and is what `/home` is usually set to, owned by `root:root`.